# How to see what query is generated by db.delete in SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to android and am wondering that how to see which SQL statement is generated by below code

```
db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, KEY_LOGCREATEDDATE + " = ?", new String[] { _date})
```

please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: put a breakpoint, select the line, ctrl+shift+I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java), Luke:

```
public int delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
    ...
    SQLiteStatement statement = new SQLiteStatement(this, "DELETE FROM " + table +
            (!TextUtils.isEmpty(whereClause) ? " WHERE " + whereClause : ""), whereArgs);
    try {
        return statement.executeUpdateDelete();
    } finally {
        statement.close();
    }
    ...
}
```